# svg with different pattern units

Tags: javascript, svg

I’m trying to do something different with SVG. Looked everywhere, can’t find if it’s even possible to do: I’ve got a flowery pattern (http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~abp4d9/) where user moves sliders (for inner circles and petals) and flowers change. 
I’ve got a button ready to use. I want it to apply random different size circles to the pattern.
Here is my inline SVG

```
<svg width="520" height="520">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="pattern" x="5" y="5" width="140" height="140"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        patternTransform="rotate(45)">
        <path d="M 0 106 156 106" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
        <g>
          <ellipse id="petal" cx=60 cy=40 rx=60 ry=10 stroke="black" stroke-          width="2" fill="white"/>
          <ellipse id="petal1" cx=60 cy=40 rx=60 ry=10 stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white" transform="rotate(35, 60, 40)"/>
          <ellipse id="petal2" cx=60 cy=40 rx=60 ry=10 stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white" transform="rotate(70, 60, 40)"/>
          <ellipse id="petal3" cx=60 cy=40 rx=60 ry=10 stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white" transform="rotate(105, 60, 40)"/>
          <ellipse id="petal4" cx=60 cy=40 rx=60 ry=10 stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white" transform="rotate(140, 60, 40)"/>
        </g>
        <circle id="circleP" cx="60" cy="40" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white"/>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
```

And parts of related JS:

```
function refresh(){
    var slider1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("slider1").value);
    document.getElementById("circleP").setAttribute("r", slider1)
}
function test() {
    var values =      [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28];
    var valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}
```

Also my flowers are cut off by some invisible line. Is it Chrome problem?

Comment: When entering code in your question, be sure to leave a blank line before and after the code block or it will not be properly formatted as code.

Comment: Have you tried your example in other browsers too? It looked the same in Firefox and Chrome here.

Comment: That's a very helpful tip about entering the code - I did struggle with it @JamesMontagne.

Comment: I have tried it in IE - the result was much worse @EricDahlstrom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The problem of petals being cut off was because I've centered them not in the middle of my SVG of 140 square: cx and cy should have been 70 & 70 not 60 & 40
2)Different pattern units are not possible in SVG

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, I am guessing you want to know how to get the button to change the slider?  Is that what you are asking?

The following should do what you want:

```
document.getElementById("slider1").value = <some random value>;
refresh();
```

```js
function randomString() {
    document.getElementById("slider1").value = getRandomInt(5,28);
    refresh();
}


function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}


function refresh(){
    console.log("a");
 var slider1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("slider1").value);
 document.getElementById("circleP").setAttribute("r", slider1)
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="slider1" type="range" min="5" max="28" onchange="refresh()" value="5"/>
    
    <input id="randomCicle" type="button" value="Press here to activate" onclick="randomString();"/>
</div>
    
<svg width="200" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
    <circle id="circleP" cx="30" cy="30" r="5"/>
</svg>
```

As to your second question.  The flower is being cut off because you are drawing off the edge (specifically the top) of the pattern area.  If you change your `patternTransform` to `"rotate(0)"`, you will be able to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: 1) I think I didn't write the question very well. The main problem now is to get the randomising button to work. I will write the question better and post it again. 2) I have looked at the pattern without rotation, like you suggested. It is the same cutting off effect. I've tried to enlarge the SVG area, x and y but to no result. I even tried to put width and height restrictions to <g> element - still cutting off. @paul

Comment: Anything drawn off the edge of the pattern area will not be present in the pattern.  You are drawing part of the flower off the top of the area.  Move the flower down and it will be fine.

Comment: Do you mean make the petals shorter? In this case the diagonal lines and flowers become asymmetric as if the flowers just stuck on top of the line - not right between the lines.

Comment: Make them shorter, or move them down. Just don't draw outside the pattern area.  Your ellipses have a long radius of 60, but they are centred at a Y of 40, so the vertically oriented ones are partially outside the pattern area.